# Create multiple azure sql db instances in a single terraform script

Tags: terraform, azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure

I have created a terraform script where it is creating 1 sql database and sql server. Now i want to create multiple sql database when running the single terraform script once.

I have the below code

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "sqlserver" {
  name          = "sql-lowers-debit1"
  resource_group_name   = local.env.rg_name
  template_body = file("${path.module}/sqldbserver.json")

  parameters        = {
    sqlServerName       = local.env.sqlServerName
    location = local.env.location
    sqlServerAdminLogin         = local.env.sqlServerAdminLogin
    sqlServerAdminLoginPassword = local.env.sqlServerAdminLoginPassword
    sqlDbName = local.env.sqlDbName
    sqlDbCollation      = local.env.sqlDbCollation
    sqlDbEdition = local.env.sqlDbEdition
    sqlDbRequestedServiceObjectiveName= local.env.sqlDbRequestedServiceObjectiveName
    }

  deployment_mode   = "Incremental"

timeouts {
    create = "20m"
  }
  depends_on = [data.azurerm_key_vault.akv]
}

data "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver" {
  name                = local.env.sqlServerName
  resource_group_name = local.env.rg_name
  depends_on = [azurerm_template_deployment.sqlserver]
}
```

I have added the below terraform variables

```
sqlDbName: "digitaltest"
sqlDbCollation: "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
sqlDbEdition: "GeneralPurpose"
sqlDbRequestedServiceObjectiveName: "Basic"
```

How do i create multiple database like digitaltest,digitaltest1,digitaltest2

Comment: is this link: https://www.thatfinnishguy.blog/2018/06/06/create-multiple-instances-with-one-terraform-module-in-oracle-cloud-infrastructure/ you can ref?

Comment: @LeonYue Somehting like this i tried but it didnt work. I am actually using deployment and creating the resources